# rewrite _prepareCollection and add custom attribute to filter for product grid

Tags: magento-1, overrides, grid

i want to rewrite the product grid like this

```
 protected function _prepareCollection() {

    parent::_prepareCollection();


    $this->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('supplier', array('eq' => 11));


    return $this;


 }
```

config.xml

```
   <blocks>
       <adminhtml>
           <rewrite>
               <catalog_product_grid>Namespace_Modulenam_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Grid</catalog_product_grid>
           </rewrite>
       </adminhtml>
   </blocks>
```

the supplier is a custom attribute, i want the products show only according to the supplier attribute, the above code still show all the products, anyone know what's wrong with about code?

Comment: add more information. how you rewrite, show your config etc.

Comment: i've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be the solution

http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/gotcha-dealt-problem-overloading-magentos-adminhtml-grid/

need to copy entire _preparecollection() and comment out 
`parent::_prepareCollection();`